# How to bind programmatically DataGrid.SelectedCells

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcell

does anyone know how to do this?

i know how to bind in Code

```
DataGrid DGrid = new DataGrid();
DGrid.SetBinding( ... , myBinding);
```

but not to `SelectedCells` because there is non `DataGrid.SelectedCellsProperty` i found only `DataGrid.SelectedIndexProperty` and `DataGrid.SelectedItemProperty`

Anything that could help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some other dependency property you can bind it to `DataGrid.SelectedCells` property.
So for example, lets assume that you have some `DependencyObject` ancestor and inside it you have some `SelectedCellsInGrid` dependency property, in this case you can call something like this:

```cs
var binding = new Binding("SelectedCells") { Source = yourDataGrid };
this.SetBinding(<your_object_type>.SelectedCellsInGridProperty, binding);
```

In case if you don't have Dependency object, well you can do this inside custom written Behavior. Leave a comment if this is your case - I'll put some additional details if needed.

Comment: oh i don't wane write a Behavior because i thing it looks like a mess so will have to create a  `DependencyObject` if i understand you right also not really what I expected. Is there no other way to do this?

Comment: If you are trying to reach your DataGrid control from within Window or UserControl, then you can declare DependencyProperty right in it (as all these derive from DependencyObject).

Comment: i build my `DataGrid` in my `ViewModel` provide it as `Property` for my `View` and now i would bind to the `SelectedCells` with an other `Property` from the same `ViewModel` thats what i want :). Sure i could "Bind" to the `selectedCellsChangedEvent` but i doesn't like it